# Response Code 400 on Authorisation Start with REST API python

Tags: rest-api, api, python

I am trying to use python to wor with the SalesForce API, and I've created all of my API keys, connected app with all permissions and everything, but when I make an authorisation call, I get response 400 - am I doing something wrong?
this is my code:

```python
import requests

params = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": "MyID", 
    "client_secret": "MySecret", 
    "username": "myloginemail@co.com", 
    "password": "MyPasswordMySecurityToken" 
}
r = requests.post("https://MYCOMPANY-dev-ed.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", params=params)
access_token = r.json().get("access_token")
instance_url = r.json().get("instance_url")
print("Access Token:", access_token)
print("Instance URL", instance_url)
```

I've now resolved it by executing a cURL call, and then passing the token into a variable to use with the python.requests library
Thanks for all the help - I'm aware of the JWT method, but for now, I'm sticking to the U:P flow

Comment: You need `Content-Type` header, see link above

Comment: Username/Password flow (aka password grant type in oAuth) is a risky flow for getting the token. The latest industry-wide best practice [disallows this flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics) in oAuth. SF follows this best practice - it now [lets admins block this flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_disable_username_password_flow.htm&type=5). Yes, you're your own admin in your org but...a few releases from now you might find SF force-blocking it. Juist sayin'. Recommended approach for app-to-app calls: JWT Bearer flow